# Angular wait for all subscriptions to complete

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, subscription

In Angular a page makes multiple http calls on multiple actions, let's say button clicks. But when the last "DONE" button is pressed I want to make sure that all those requests are finished before it progresses. I tried to use `forkJoin` with observables but it triggers requests itself which is not what I want to do, I want other actions to trigger requests and just to make sure that async requests are finished when "DONE" is clicked. With promises I would just push promises to array and then do `Promise.all(allRequests).then(()=>{})`

```
observables: Observable<any>[];

onBtn1Click(){
   let o1 = this.service.doAction1();
   this.observables.push(o1);
   
   o1.subscribe(resp => {
        //do action1
   });
}

onBtn2Click(){
   let o2 = this.service.doAction2();
   this.observables.push(o2);
   
   o2.subscribe(resp => {
        //do action2
   });
}

onDoneClick(){
   // I would like something like this just that it wouldn't trigger the requests but make sure they are completed. 
   forkJoin(this.observables).subscribe(()=>{
     //Proceed with other things
   });
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `finalize()` operator in Rxjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless someone comes up with an elegant approach, the following should do it.

I'm creating an object to hold hot observable for each cold observable from the HTTP request. The request would emit to it's corresponding hot observable using RxJS `finalize` operator. These hot observables could then be combined using `forkJoin` with a `take(1)` to wait for the source requests to complete.

```js
private httpReqs: { [key: string]: ReplaySubject<boolean> } = Object.create(null);

onBtn1Click() {
  this.httpReqs['btn1'] = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);
  this.service.doAction1().pipe(
    finalize(() => this.httpReqs['btn1'].next(true))
  ).subscribe(resp => {
    // do action1
  });
}

onBtn2Click() {
  this.httpReqs['btn2'] = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);
  this.service.doAction1().pipe(
    finalize(() => this.httpReqs['btn2'].next(true))
  ).subscribe(resp => {
    // do action2
  });
}

onDoneClick(){
  forkJoin(
    Object.values(this.httpReqs).map(repSub =>
      repSub.asObservable().pipe(
        take(1)
      )
    )
  ).subscribe(() => {
    // Proceed with other things
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks works fine. I just use `let rs = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1); httpReqs.push(rs); rs.next(true)` instead of assigning to named properties.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using `shareReplay`

If you multicast, any subscriber who subscribes to a completed stream gets the `complete` notification. You can leverage that.

The various share operators have an implicit `refCount` that changes its default every few RxJS versions. The current version for `shareReplay(n)` is pretty intuitive, but you may need to set `refCount:false` on older versions, or even use `multicast(new ReplaySubject(1)), refCount()`

```js
onBtn1Click(){
  let o1 = this.service.doAction1().pipe(
    shareReplay(1)
  );
  this.observables.push(o1);
   
  o1.subscribe(resp => {
    //do action1
  });
}
```

This is the smallest change that should get your code working the way you'd like

#### Scan to count activity

You can avoid forkJoin entirely if you just count currently active operations.

```js
count = (() => {
  const cc = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  return {
    start: () => cc.next(1),
    stop: () => cc.next(-1),
    value$: cc.pipe(
      scan((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0)
    )
  }
})();

onBtn1Click(){
  this.count.start();

  this.service.doAction1().pipe(
    finalize(this.count.stop)
  ).subscribe(resp => {
    //do action1
  });
}

onDoneClick(){
  this.count.value$.pipe(
    first(v => v === 0) // Wait until nothing is currently active
  ).subscribe(() => {
    //Proceed with other things
  });

}
```